# PHP acts differently depending on computer

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have an issue with php where code works on on computer but wont work on another

```
    function appendParam(&$req, $name, $value) {
    if (req == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (name == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (value != null) {
        $req[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

The above works on one computer and is capable of checking req and name against null properly and the variables is the if condition don't need dollar signs (when i put the dollar signs in they break on this computer)

but i need to use the following code on another computer to get the same end result

```
    function appendParam(&$req, $name, $value) {
    if ($value != null) {
        $req[$name] = $value;
    }   
    if ($name == null) {
        return;
    }
    if ($req == null) {
        return;
    }
}
```

on this other computer it isn't capable of checking name or req against null (it breaks)
and i need the dollar signs on the variables in the if condition.

As a side note it also seems that this computer can't read from an array index that isn't already initialized.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check if your php.ini files are equal to each other.

Comment: "variables" in php without sigil? could they be defined constants?

Comment: I'm sure that they are not constants, and any changes that would have been made to the php.ini by me are identical otherwise are enforced by the existing software that I'm integrating with.

Comment: does the first piece of code produce the same result on both machines?

Comment: re: your side note.  if you are trying to read from the array without using the $, then php might think you're trying to access a constant with value of type array, which is not allowed

Comment: the first piece of code breaks on the second machine, thats why i use the second piece on that machine (same end result, but no checks :( )

and my side note refers to arrays with the dollar sign, everywhere else in the code I use dollar signs for variables, it just breaks in that one function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 machines might have different warning levels or error reporting levels.

I'm confused, surely you should have the $ prefix before any php variable name otherwise you're not actually checking on the variable? What are you trying to achieve by not using the $ prefix

Comment: i want to use the dollar prefix, but it stops on the first line that has a variable with a dollar sign in the if condition

Comment: whats your calling code look like.  and like @daniel said,can you give some examples and error messages

Comment: I believe you're right.  Without the $/sigil, PHP think's the identifier is a constant, but if no such constant exists, it can "fall back" to the variable that would've been referred to if the "$" was there.  However, this generates some warning/notice level (forget the exact level) and may not always work as expected...

Comment: So from my understanding with out the dollar sign it uses a variable if a constant isn't available but even if its throwing a warning its not stopping the code since this is actually working. It passes req and name check.

Comment: SOLUTION BY david archer: use empty function to check nulls instead of directly checking with equal signs.

Answer (score 2):

This code makes very little sense to me:

```
    function appendParam(&$req, $name, $value) {
    if ($value != null) {
                $req[$name] = $value;
        }       
    if ($name == null) {
                return;
        }
    if ($req == null) {
                return;
        }
}
```

It should be written like so:

```
function appendParam(&$req, $name, $value)
{
 if(empty($name) || empty($value) || empty($req))
  return;

 $req[$name] = $value;
}
```

When you say it "breaks" can you give a specific example/error you're getting and how you're using the function? I'm thinking you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Your code won't always have the same effect as his.  In his case if value is not null, then req can be set.  Your will bail if req is null even if value is set

Comment: i understand that i should check name and req first,  but it won't work (with or without the dollar sign). Is there an actual difference between checking the value against null and calling it in the empty function?

The error is it doesn't get past the name check if it ever gets there, just stops. It also doesn't seem to write out to the log when this occurs.

Comment: @chronoXiii, see @peter's comment to my answer.  You should always use the $, your problem is something else

Comment: @davidarcher, your empty function over checking variables against null works, so now i can actually check name and req on both computers. Now my only issue seems to be the dollar signs.
THX

Comment: well, it was @daniels answer to do that (+1 to him). Now I suggest you experiment. try "echo"ing e.g $req, $value, $name (with the $) as you enter the function.  See what you get

Comment: Can you paste some sample input to the question.  The logic is slightly different between your two functions

Comment: I forgot i could just do !($empty ($value)), :P
now I'm capable of running the same code on both computers
thx for everyone's help

Comment: How do i give david archer proper credit? Do i just comment the solution in his answer and then checkmark?

Comment: !($empty ($value)) ? do you mean !(empty($value))  ?

Comment: oh right sorry typo on the comment :P, thx again
its !(empty($value))

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of best practices to be honored in order to simplify the debugging of this issue, these BP also will make the problem arise more clearly and hopefully solve it at its root ...

1) first of all you should assure that your php.ini are consistent and that the following parameters are set to they optimal value:

> allow_asp_tag = Off                  ; there is no need to have such a tag usually
>   short_open_tags = Off                ; this avoids headaches when working with xml data/documents
>   register_globals = Off               ; this is the evil pre-4.1 default
>   log_errors = On                      ; this two lines
>   show_errors = Off                    ; are hopeful in production envs, when security is a need
>   error_reporting = `E_ALL & E_STRICT` ; This makes every error to be displayed

2) avoid the use of the "@" operator to cut out error messages, the have to be handled, not hidden!  Moreover this is a performance issue

3) choose the right construct, operator or function to test conditions.
I.E., if you are testing a variable is not "empty" not test it against the empty string ($v==""), this seems to work in general, but it relies on the implicit cast that the operator == forces, if you'd have used the === operator the test would not been what you wanted, of course

4) as Daniel pointed out, the function may be rewritten in a better way:

```
function appendParam(&$req, $name, $value)
{
    if (empty($name) || empty($value) || empty($req)) {

        return;
    }
    $req[$name] = $value; 
}
```

If you [want|can]'t change your php ini it's a good practice to 
runtime set the log level, setting it in a config file as a debugging feature for example

```
    error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT;
```

My answer is to fully enable every error reporting, and PHP will tell you something is strange, that strangeness (probably it will be a NOTICE) will be the root of you issue.

My 2 cents :)

Comment: In addition to my post and referring @Daniel too, it should be noticed that the
function proposed is better than the starting one, but it is still having a bad argument checking policy.

I mean that silently returning null if a required argument is empty is not a good check and, above all, is is not a good way to make a possible wrong function call to be aware of the error.

Take into account the idea of using assertions instead, custom errors by mean of trigger_error(), or a more complex error handling mechanism such as exceptions ...

My 2 cents :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be one of the computers is using an older version of PHP?

Comment: I thought that it could be the reason but after checking, they are both using the same version